# How to tell server to display 404 page

Tags: php

How to display 404 page when the user is not found.
Consider a website extracting username from $_GET variable like

```
example.com/users/?username=johndoe // Normal john doe's profile will be displayed
```

and

```
example.com/users/?username=jimmy //Should display 404 page without changing url
```

If a user is not found found in database.It should show a 404 page.


**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: much triviality ... to start by searching a jedi must

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found");
echo "Sorry, but user not found :("; //or include your 404 html file
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if user is in database, if not, you can include an error page.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "abc123", "db_name");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ".$_GET['username']);
if($result == false)
{
    require('error.php');
    exit();
}

// Contine displaying user page.
```

Make sure to check SQL injection!